# How to Update a page in Spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Can someone please point me to the right direction, it is a very simple spring form that I'm trying to edit. I have tried various examples from net but can not get it working.

```
<form:form id="myForm" modelAttribute="contacts" method="Post" action="contacts.html" commandName="contacts">

        <label>First Name<span class="small">Edit your first name</span></label>
        <form:input path="firstName" /><br>
        <form:errors path="firstName" cssClass="error" /><br>

        <label>Last Name<span class="small">Edit your last name</span></label>
        <form:input path="lastName" /><br>
        <form:errors path="lastName" cssClass="error" /><br>

        <button type="submit">Amend</button>
    </form:form>

protected static final String EDIT_VIEW_KEY = "editForm";

@Autowired
private ContactsService conService;

@RequestMapping(value="/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showEditForm(@PathVariable("id") Integer id,
        @ModelAttribute("contacts") Contacts contacts,Model model){

    model.addAttribute("contacts", conService.listContactsById(id));
    return EDIT_VIEW_KEY;
}
```

and the error I'm getting is this;

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'firstName' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property 'firstName' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:729)
org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:721)
org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:147)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:178)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:198)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:164)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:151)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:142)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:126)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:421)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.editForm_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(editForm_jsp.java:214)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.editForm_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(editForm_jsp.java:173)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.editForm_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(editForm_jsp.java:128)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.editForm_jsp._jspService(editForm_jsp.java:85)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:684)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:678)
org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:103)
org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:96)
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.write(ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.java:76)
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:336)
org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:210)
org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.end(InsertAttributeModel.java:126)
org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:311)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.layout_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f3(layout_jsp.java:180)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.layout_jsp._jspService(layout_jsp.java:98)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:241)
org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:222)
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:690)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:644)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:627)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1157)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:927)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Many thanks

Comment: Are you sure conService.listContactsById(id) returns the instance itself and not the arraylist of the instance

Comment: Thanks, Yes it is returning the list I wasn't sure how else to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing back a list to your form:

```
Invalid property 'firstName' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]
```

Your form expects things like a `firstName` field.

In general, a list won't have a `firstName` field, although they might contain a *collection* of objects that have a `firstName` field. Did you mean to iterate over the list with a form per item?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes I am passing back the list because that's the only way I knew, how else can I do it ?

Comment: @Zed420 Pass back a single element?

Answer (score 0):

you are using `modelAttribute="contacts"` in form and I think that contacts is ArrayList so it is not contains firstName, if your list have object of bean contains "firstName" you can use  to iterate on it or use `modelAttribute="contacts[${i}]"` and set i using  with the value you want.